# How to upgrade new version of module code by using composer in Magento 2 from third party repository

Tags: magento2, composer, third-party-module

We have installed third party modules successfully using command `composer update` by Adding below repository to `composer.json`

```
"repositories": {
    "0": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://exampleurl.com"
    },
    "magento": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://exampleurl.com"
    }
},
```

Now few of the modules have been updated/edited in the third party repository(https://exampleurl.com).

1. How can we get those latest module changes into my instance by using composer.
2. Running `composer update` again is suggested ?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: yes, iam also have a third party module its latest version is released, how can i upgrade to latest version of module, I have chaged the module files.